# Bootstrap - scrollbar is not visible in mobile, especially firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How it is possible to make scroll bar visible in mobile devices. The script below make visible only in default Android browser. But in Firefox is not visible.
In Chrome it is visible only when we touch the display.
How it is possible to make is visible in all devices and browsers as well.

```
.table-responsive::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  }

.table-responsive::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 12px;
}

.table-responsive::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 12px;
}

.table-responsive::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

.table-responsive::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 10px;  
    background-color: #ffffff; 
}
```

Comment: its browser behavior ... to save space and people really use to idea of touch and swip ...

Answer (score 0):

In case of Firefox, there is no `::-webkit-scrollbar` equivalent. See: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77790.

Try using a jQuery plugin (jScrollPane) instead. Check fiddle example for working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VYcDZ/51/