# How to disable auto-hiding scrollbars in bootstrap (preferably without a plugin)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, scrollbar

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34448960/bootstrap-scrollbar-is-not-visible-in-mobile-especially-firefox) question, which is exactly what I need, but the only answer is for a plugin that is years old and no longer updated. Is there any way to achieve this without using a plugin? And if a plugin is the only option, are there any newer ones available?

My specific issue is that sometimes tables are cut off at just the right place, that it looks as if they are complete. I need the scrollbar to be visible so users know there is more information. Also, some charts are interactive, and do not allow scrolling except when using the actual scrollbar (which is difficult when you can't see it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be helpfull.
[Webkit Scrollbars](https://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/)

Comment: I can't tell you how many times I saw that and tried it, but failed. Turns out I had to do both background and thumb to get it to appear correctly. Thanks. `::-webkit-scrollbar { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { background: #C6C6C6; }` Also, have to specify `overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: auto;`